# Delete duplicate elements (separated by comma) in a character vector in R

Tags: r, arrays, regex, string

I have a character vector that looks like this:

```
 vector

 "Narcos: Mexico, Narcos, Narcos: Mexico"
 "V for Vendetta, Narcos: Mexico"
 "Criminal: France, Criminal UK, Criminal: France"
 "V for Vendetta"
 ...
```

what I want to do is to get rid of duplicate titles from for each row, where every title is separated by a comma:

```
 "Narcos: Mexico, Narcos"
 "V for Vendetta, Narcos: Mexico"
 "Criminal: France, Criminal UK"
 "V for Vendetta"
 ...
```

data

```
vector1 <- c("Narcos: Mexico, Narcos, Narcos: Mexico", "V for Vendetta, Narcos: Mexico", 
"Criminal: France, Criminal UK, Criminal: France", "V for Vendetta"
)
```

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` i.e `dput(vector)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah done

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(your_vector, ', '), function(i)toString(unique(i)))`